# Batch class failed to update the Account name Field

Tags: apex, batch, account

We have a Account object and I did wrote a Batch class that will update the Account name with 'Mr.' in front of it. However it did not updated the Account records Name.

Account Batch Code:-

```
global class AccountBatch implements database.Batchable<Sobject> {

global Database.QueryLocator start(database.BatchableContext bc)
{
    String query = 'select id, Name from Account';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}
global void execute(database.BatchableContext bc,List<Account> Scope)
{
    List<Account> acc = new List<Account>();
    for(Account a: acc)
    {
        a.Name ='Mr.'+a.Name;
        acc.add(a);
    }
    update acc;
}
    global void finish(database.BatchableContext bc){} 
}
```

Please advise.

Thank You,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are instantiating a new list of Account records in your execute method.

As you can see, the `execute` method of the batch classes receive a list of records as parameter. The records you query in the `start` method.

So you just have to loop through the list received as parameter like this:

```
global void execute(database.BatchableContext bc,List<Account> Scope)
{
    for(Account a: Scope)
    {
        a.Name ='Mr.'+a.Name;
    }
    update Scope;
}
```

Is there a reason why you're updating all the Account names instead of adding a new formula field on the Account object?
You can add a formula of type text with this code:

```
'Mr.' & Name
```

Comment: This is a UAT environment which has a 2000+ accounts and My lead requires a Batch class from me. ,Also I tried your code it still did not updated the Account name field in Account records

Comment: What are the logs of the execution of the batch? It should work.

Comment: I have a question here. Just saving the Batch class will run the batch right? (Updating the records)

Comment: No it doesn't. You can schecule a batch if you want to run it regularly. But in your case, you can just run it from the developer console like [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000171199&language=en_US&type=1).

Comment: This batch would keep adding `Mr.` everytime the batch runs and is not flexible. @MartinLezer mentioned to use a formula field is much better solution. If you still want to update it, you can create a formula field and update records where Name is not equal to the formula.

Comment: @Martin the statement execute section in the log is blank

Comment: @MartinLezer however the status of the Batch is Success , But in account the records did not updated

Comment: @MartinLezer This was successfull there was a trigger that stopping the record from update . Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Update your class.

```
global class AccountBatch implements database.Batchable<Sobject> {

    global Database.QueryLocator start(database.BatchableContext bc)
    {
        String query = 'select id, Name from Account';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global void execute(database.BatchableContext bc,List<Account> Scope)
    {
        List<Account> acc = new List<Account>();
        for(Account a: Scope)
        {
            a.Name ='Mr.'+a.Name;
            acc.add(a);
        }
        update acc;
    }
        global void finish(database.BatchableContext bc){} 
}
```

And execute the Batch Class from Developer Console's 'Execute Anonymous' window.

```
Database.executeBatch(new AccountBatch());
```

Comment: I don't think your answer is very much different than of Martin's, He had already specified how to run the batch in his answer's comment.

Comment: @ForceMars This is also not working I tried and it did not updated Account records